# How to integrate over an arbitrarily positioned spherical cap in spherical coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, surfaces

If you want to integrate over the SURFACE of a spherical cap that is positioned in the way it is on wikipedia, this is rather simple. since it has azimuthal symmetry you get a factor $2\pi$ and for the altitude one just needs to integrate from $0$ to $\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle that refers to the position. 
[Spherical cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap)

Now I need to find out how to do this, if the cap is not symmetric around the z-axis but somewhere on the sphere. So I am looking for the most general way to find the integration interval for integration over the surface of a spherical cap. (Notice, I just need the interval). Since the integrand is highly ugly and unsymmetric I cannot reduce it to this general case with azimuthal symmetry.

Therefore, does anybody know how to integrate over the surface of an arbitrarily positioned spherical cap?

Comment: What do you mean by "not symmetric around the z-axis, but somewhere on the sphere"? Do you mean somewhere *else* on the sphere?

Comment: yes, that was what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the vector field to match the re-positioning of the cap. Just multiply the field by a rotation matrix:

$$\vec{f}'(x,y,z)=R\vec{f}(x,y,z)$$

Then integrate $\vec{f}'(x,y,z)$ over the cap symmetric about the z-axis.

Comment: thank you, actually this is a helpful trick